# Indexing xml/svg file with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, svg, indexing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have an svg file that has titles with unique Id's, looking like this:

```
<title id="t0">
<title id="t1">
```

There are many thousands of these titles.

Here's how I create a BS object from the svg:

```
svg = open('counties.svg', 'r').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(svg, 'xml')
paths = soup.findAll('path')
```

So I am able to pull out the style of each path, but I cannot pull the title in the same fashion:

```
for p in paths:
   p['style'] = "font-size:12px..." #this works
   p['title'] = "title for path..." #this doesnt work
```

I suspect this is because the 'title' section has a unique Id.

here's a sample of what a "path" looks like

```
  <path d="M 405.190,251.879 L 405.748,257.292 L 401.350,257.81 L 401.012,254.629 L 400.885,253.474 L 401.300,253.43 L 401.430,253.322 L 401.300,252.294 L 405.190,251.879" id="01031" style="font-size:12px;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-opacity:1;
    stroke-width:0.1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-linecap:butt;
    marker-start:none;stroke-linejoin:bevel;fill:#bcbddc">
   <title id="t31">
    Coffee, AL
   </title>
  </path>
```

How do I properly index the title so I can alter its contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for p in paths:
   p['style'] = "font-size:102px" #this works
   p.title.string = "title for path..."
```

Comment: Works! Thank you!